# ServiceHost is binding to multiple hostnames/base addresses

Tags: c#, wcf, acl

I'm running Windows 7 and Visual C# Express 2010.

I have the following rule in my ACL:

```
Reserved URL            : http://www.example.com:8020/gamerecords/
User: Myricae\Dario
    Listen: Yes
    Delegate: No
    SDDL: D:(A;;GX;;;S-1-5-21-3389095862-38437692-3014067205-1001)
```

Not that it really matters, but I also have an appropriate entry in my *hosts* file:

```
127.0.0.1       www.example.com
```

I'm trying to self-host a WCF service within a console application:

```
var baseAddress = new Uri("http://www.example.com:8020/gamerecords/");

using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Acme.Gaming.GameRecordsImpl), baseAddress))
{
    ...
}
```

I get the following exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.AddressAccessDeniedException: HTTP could not register URL http://+:8020/gamerecords/. Your process does not have access rights to this namespace (see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=70353 for details). ---> System.Net.HttpListenerException: Access is denied
```

The reason is that **ServiceHost** tries to bind to any hostname (**+**), but the ACL rule only authorizes the current user for hostname *www.example.com*. If I change the rule to:

```
Reserved URL            : http://+:8020/gamerecords/
User: Myricae\Dario
    Listen: Yes
    Delegate: No
    SDDL: D:(A;;GX;;;S-1-5-21-3389095862-38437692-3014067205-1001)
```

everything works fine. However I don't think that **ServiceHost** should really try to bind to any hostname; instead it should only publish the service at *www.example.com*. **Why WCF attempts to bind to multiple hostnames?**.

I found [a page](http://www.differentpla.net/content/2008/03/odd-behaviour-wcf-base-addresses-and-httpsys-wildcards) which describes a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

Did you start your application via **"Run-as-Administrator"**?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The reason why I populate the ACL with those rules is because I want to avoid running the application with administrator privileges. If I run the application as administrator it works, but I can't understand why it tries to bind to any hostname instead of *www.example.com* only.

Comment: I think not only WCF, in general if you need to open a port on a machine Windows requires that you Run-as-Administrator. Check this out - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730935(v=vs.110).aspx